# Empty a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Previously, I was given the advice of clearing a GridView by setting its `DataSource` to `null` and calling `DataBind()`. However, I get an exception thrown when I do this:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index
```

This exception isn't a very hard one to diagnose. The problem is, how can I clear out my GridView for when the `DataSource` is empty?

EDIT: Here is the full function that populates the `GridView`:

```
void PopulateGridView()
    {
        //Connect to database and get frames for selected job
        var dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            _connectionToDatabase.Open(); //open database

            var findDataCommand = new SqlCommand(SkidListSpName, _connectionToDatabase) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

            findDataCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(SlParameter1, JobRelPhase_DropDown.SelectedValue));
            findDataCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(SlParameter2, _stationId));

            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(findDataCommand);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gridView.DataSource = dt;
                gridView.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                gridView.DataSource = null; //HERE is where I set the DataSource
                gridView.DataBind(); //removing this removes the exception
                StatusLabel.Text = "No items found.";
            }

            _connectionToDatabase.Close(); //close database
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "No items found.";
            TestLabel.Text = e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            _connectionToDatabase.Close(); //close database
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `EmptyDataTemplate` to show some custom text to indicate there are no records, if that's OK.

Comment: that looks weird, it shouldn't throw the exception on assigning `null` to `DataSource` Could you try clean/rebuild your application and also are you sure you are getting exception on `gridView.DataBind()` ?

Comment: When I comment out that DataBind(), the exception is no longer thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try gridView.Rows.Clear();  It should just clear out the gridView leaving you with an empty body but column headers still there.

Comment: I think you're thinking of DataGridView. GridView doesn't seem to have this method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set your datasource to null, what if you create a new datatable and set the datasource to that. Should do the job...